# How do I execute a program with default variables?

Tags: bash, alias, execute-command

How can I execute a program (specifically a bash alias) with the default environment variables?

Consider this example:

```
export test="something I dont want to exist"

alias _xterm='xterm -fn 7x13 -fa "Ubuntu Mono:size=12:antialias=false"'

_xterm
```

In the spawned `xterm` instance, the variable `$test` shouldn't be set.

Comment: Do you know what the variables are explicitly or are you just trying to get all the defaults?

Comment: @Oli the `$TMUX` variable specifically, but I'd rather not manually unset it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You could execute your command in an empty environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48994/how-to-run-a-program-in-a-clean-environment-in-bash):

```
env -i _xterm
```

---

A quick test harness:

```
$ export TMUX=3
$ bash -c 'echo $TMUX'
3
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $TMUX'
# nothing echos
```

---

Preserving `$DISPLAY`, `$USER`, etc:

```
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $DISPLAY'
# nothing
$ env -i DISPLAY=$DISPLAY bash -c 'echo $DISPLAY'
:0
```

---

Or you could explicitly exclude just some variables with the `env -u` option:

```
$ export TMUX=3
$ env -u TMUX bash -c 'echo $TMUX'
# nothing
```

Comment: If you're testing, make sure you're not using `''` quotes or your variable will be substituted before it enters the subshell. DISPLAY et al are going to be a problem with this approach that you'll have to manually cater for.

Comment: `bash: _xterm: command not found`, I assume it's an alias problem. Why would this happen even if it's in my `.bashrc`? Occurs even with the exclude way

Comment: Yeah I've been trying for the past 20 minutes to get the alias to copy over. I've got to `env -i ALIAS="$(alias _xterm)" DISPLAY=$DISPLAY bash -c '. <(echo "$ALIAS") && alias && _xterm'` and it still doesn't work (despite working)... You could write a script instead of an alias. That would probably work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out that using a function works as expected so I used that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The names of default environment variables are written with capital letters. Now, assuming that you will define new environment variables with tiny letters (as it is in your example `test`), instead to use a simple alias `_xterm`, you can use a function `_xterm` where you have to unset the new environment variables and keep only the default environment variables for the new shell instance:

```
_xterm () {
    for var in $(env | cut -d"=" -f1)
    do
        if [[ ! "$var" =~ [^a-z] ]]; then
            unset $var   #or env -u $var
        fi
    done
    xterm -fn 7x13 -fa "Ubuntu Mono:size=12:antialias=false"
}
```

Like this, your new environment variables are not available in the new shell instance, but when you comeback to the old shell instance you can still use them.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good alternate solution, but maybe I wasn't specific in my question. I actually wanted to unset the `$TMUX` variable so that the spawned xterm instance would be able to run tmux (as Oli asked and demonstrated)

Comment: @minerz029 Ok, no problem, then you can add another line: `elif [ "$var" = "TMUX" ]; then unset $var` before `fi`. The same for other env variables with capital letters.

Comment: @minerz029 I gave you an example, but you can adapt it as you wish.